# Is there anyway to get around the SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when accessing a website through https when it does not have ssl?

Tags: ssl, web, redirect, server, protocols

I have a simple Portfolio website with the domain address razifalah.com.
I use this domain for email server and I also use it to redirect clients to another domain address,
However if i use the https protocol instead if the http I get this error:

[image]

Is there anyway i could get around this without changing the name server or enabling encryption?

Comment: _"when accessing a website through https when it does not have ssl?"_ - so you'd like to know how to use the drive-thru at a McDonalds when you don't have a car...?

Comment: I don't want to access ssl, i want to avoid accessing it. is there anyway to redirect https to http before getting that error?

Comment: ...so don't use `https` then, use `http` - but ideally **you should** be using HTTPS - so why aren't you? PKI certificates for using HTTPS are free from vendors like LetsEncrypt (i.e. Google): https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: Don't use it? tell that to google search engine. Also as i mentioned i can't change the nameserver because I'm using the domain for an email server.

Comment: May I ask what your current level of understanding of DNS is? You _do know_ that email uses MX records, not A/CNAME records, right? So your concerns about breaking your email are unfounded.

Comment: Most ssl providers such as cloudflare have asked me to change the nameserver. will i be able to apply ssl without braking the email using let's encrypt ?

Comment: Correct. Just make sure your MX records are the same as they are now when you switch nameservers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> get around the SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when accessing a website through https ... without ... enabling encryption?

It is impossible to access a site by HTTPS if HTTPS is not properly enabled. DNS is irrelevant for this.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really need SSL i just wanted to avoid this error by maybe redirecting clients to http once entering https. I've enabled ssl instaed